# sencha touch 2 issue with Ext.List

Tags: listview, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a problem displaying my Ext.list component. 
Here is my code:

```
Ext.define("iphone.view.customers.List", {

extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype: 'customersList',

config: {

    fullscreen: true,
    title: 'Customers List',
    ui: 'round',
    itemTpl: [ '{title}' ],

    data: [
        { title: 'Item 1' },
        { title: 'Item 2' },
        { title: 'Item 3' },
        { title: 'Item 4' }
    ]
}
});
```

When i launch the application the console produce this warning and nothing appears:

> [WARN][Anonymous] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Ext.data.Store';
>   consider adding 'Ext.data.Store' explicitly as a require of the
>   corresponding class

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see that warning because the best practice to do it in Sencha Touch 2 is:

- Define your `Ext.data.Store` with `data` config (inline data in this case)
- Suppose your defined Store is `listStore`, then use this config: `store: listStore` in your list definition

Hope this helps.

An example for your situation:

```
Ext.define('iphone.store.Customers', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'iphone.model.Customer',
            data: [
                      { title: 'Item 1' },
                      { title: 'Item 2' },
                      { title: 'Item 3' },
                      { title: 'Item 4' }
                    ]
    }
});
```

and list:

```
Ext.define("iphone.view.customers.List", {

extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype: 'customersList',

config: {

    fullscreen: true,
    title: 'Customers List',
    ui: 'round',
    itemTpl: [ '{title}' ],

    store: 'Customers'
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already added inline data with the data config as you can see in my code and the list doesnot appear also.

Comment: I've updated some code, typically you should do that way, if there're errors, they are minor ones which might be relevant to layout config. Please let me know if you still get errors